# Hide cursor in Chrome (and IE)

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

I have the following CSS that hides the mouse cursor for anything on the web page. It works perfectly in Firefox, but in IE and Chrome, it doesn't work.

```
html {
    cursor: none;
}
```

In Chrome, I always see the mouse pointer. In IE, however, I see whatever cursor was last 'active' when it entered the screen. Presumably it's keeping the last selection instead of removing it.

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Because I have a customer facing screen that has no human interaction.  When the box starts up it automatically fires up the web browser but the cursor automatically starts in the center of the screen which masks part of the web page.  So it needs to be hidden.

Comment: Since cursor can be given a url to use, could you use a url to a blank image?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with an image.  I tried pointing it to a 16x16 .png file I had (which was visible) just to see if I could change it, it didn't seem to work though.  Maybe .cur files only?

Comment: You could alternatively use another browser for your display. Hitting F11 on most browsers will make them fullscreen.

Comment: It is already run in Kiosk mode.  I have no control over the browser used.

Comment: I guess they added this feature to Chrome. using "cursor: none;" works perfectly in Chrome.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This property `cursor:none;` isn't part of the standard

See here [w3c cursor CSS properties](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_cursor.asp).

You might want to look into hiding it with Javascript or JQuery.

Also, look at blank cursor files [here](http://pc.autons.net/stuff/blanks/).

And one last link to an [ajax solution](http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-create-custom-image-cursors.html).

Chrome has had this issue since it was built, there have been reports sent to the people at [Chromium](http://code.google.com/chromium/), and I assume they are working on it.

Also, don't trust that anything would work in IE. Ever. :P

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem in these days and found a good solution to hide the pointer in Google Chrome.

This is the [W3C definition](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_cursor.asp) of url property:

> A comma separated of URLs to custom
>   cursors. Note: Always specify a
>   generic cursor at the end of the list,
>   in case none of the URL-defined
>   cursors can be used

So, you can define a url to *not completely transparent* image, followed by the default pointer:

```
cursor: url(img/almost_transparent.png), default;
```

If you choose a totally transparent png, Chrome will display a black rectangle instead, but if you choose a png with at least 1px not transparent it will work, and nobody will notice the pointer.

Comment: Just to let you know Chrome supports "cursor: none;" and IE supports fully transparent cursors. You can use browser specific stylesheets. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. At the time of my answer Chrome didn't support cursor:none

Comment: Could get it to work on IE and Edge (via browserstack)

Answer (score 7):

Finding something that works across browsers is a pain.

The code below works on Chrome, IE, and Firefox. IE likes .cur files, Chrome likes the embedded png, and some browsers actually respect the none :)

```
div {
    cursor: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAFBhaW50Lk5FVCB2My41LjbQg61aAAAADUlEQVQYV2P4//8/IwAI/QL/+TZZdwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='),
    url(images/blank.cur),
    none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the best way to deal with this now is the pointer lock api.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Pointer_Lock

It'll hide the mouse cursor, but give you access to the data about mouse movement as well.

Comment: From the website: `This is an experimental technology` == Not good for users with slightly older browsers

Comment: Correct. It's great though for other specific use cases. (Kiosk-ey touchscreens)

Comment: Pointer lock is definitely the wrong thing to do if you just want to hide the mouse.

Answer (score -1):

In css:  `* { cursor: url(cursor.png), none !important }`

Answer (score -5):

Use a hidden applet with the java.awt.robot class to move the cursor off the sreen. Say the very lower left corner.

Comment: Wow... I can't think of a harder and more complicated way to accomplish such a simple task.

Comment: I +1 this. It's not a simple task. cursor:none; does "work" in Chrome, but if you click the left mouse button the cursor reappears. If you try and drag, the cursor reappears. If you are able to do something like open-and-close the inspector, the cursor reappears. There are *lots* of ways to get it back. This solution is the kind of thing that provides permanent cursor removal, should your application require it.